# Exercise 16.1 of Jech's Set Theory

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

Exercise 16.1 of Jech's *Set Theory* says:

> $B(P * \dot{Q}) = B(P) * B(\dot{Q})$.

Here, $P$ and $Q$ are (forcing) posets, and $B(P)$ and $B(Q)$ are their respective Boolean completions.

Lemma 16.3 of Jech tells us that $B(P) * B(\dot{Q})$ is a complete Boolean algebra, so it suffices to show that $P * \dot{Q}$ embeds densely into $B(P) * B(\dot{Q})$. Honestly, I'm not too sure what should the embedding be, but motivated by Lemma 16.3 I tried to define the embedding $\pi : P * \dot{Q} \to B(P) * B(\dot{Q})$ by stipulating that $\pi((p,\dot{q}))$ is the unique $\dot{c} \in B(P) * B(\dot{Q})$ such that:
$$
\|\dot{c} = \dot{q}\| = p \text{ and } \|\dot{c} = -\dot{q}\| = -p
$$
However, I don't think we can ensure that this $\pi$ is injective (and I am not even sure if it is a Boolean algebra homomorphism), so I'm stuck here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with taking the canonical embedding $\pi_P\colon P\to B(P)$ and a name for the canonical embedding $\dot\pi_Q\colon\dot Q\to B(\dot Q)$ and defining $\pi(p,\dot q)=(\pi_P(p),\dot\pi_Q(\dot q))$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm following Jech's definition of $B(P) * B(\dot{Q})$, which is defined using equivalence classes of elements in $Q$. I don't see a straightforward way to apply your suggestion to Jech's definition.

Comment: If you want to talk about a homomorphism from $\Bbb{R/Q}$ to some group, the sensible thing is to define a homomorphism from $\Bbb R$ which can be lifted to the quotient. This understanding extends to many other situations.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm afraid I have no idea what you're saying helps. Again, Jech's definition of $B(P) * B(Q)$ convolutes me, and I have no idea how to see it as a "product" of $B(P)$ and $B(Q)$.

Comment: My point is that 5he definitions in Jech rely on quotients and dense embeddings, and we can use these to simplify our proof. Show that the obvious thing plays nice with those and you're done.